# Convert image to bytes and then write to new file

Tags: rust

I'm trying to take an image that is converted into a vector of bytes and write those bytes to a new file. The first part is working, and my code is compiling, but the new file that is created ends up empty (nothing is written to it). What am I missing?

Is there a cleaner way to convert `Vec<u8>` into `&[u8]` so that it can be written? The way I'm currently doing it seems kind of ridiculous...

```
use std::os;
use std::io::BufferedReader;
use std::io::File;
use std::io::BufferedWriter;

fn get_file_buffer(path_str: String) -> Vec<u8> {
    let path = Path::new(path_str.as_bytes());
    let file = File::open(&path);
    let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
    match reader.read_to_end() {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(_) => vec![0],
    }
}

fn main() {
    let file = get_file_buffer(os::args()[1].clone());

    let mut new_file = File::create(&Path::new("foo.png")).unwrap();
    let mut writer = BufferedWriter::new(new_file);

    writer.write(String::from_utf8(file).unwrap().as_bytes()).unwrap();
    writer.flush().unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a `Vec<T>`, you can get a `&[T]` out of it in two ways:

- Take a reference to a dereference of it, i.e. `&*file`; this works because `Vec<T>` implements `Deref<[T]>`, so `*file` is effectively of type `[T]` (though doing that without borrowing it, i.e. `&*file`, is not legal).
- Call the [`as_slice()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice) method.

As the [`BufWriter` docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) say, “the buffer will be written out when the writer is dropped”, so that `writer.flush().unwrap()` is not strictly necessary, serving only to make handling of errors explicit.

But as for the behaviour you describe, that I mostly do not observe. So long as you do not encounter any I/O errors, the version not using the `String` dance will work fine, while with the `String` dance it will panic if the input data is not legal UTF-8 (which if you’re dealing with images it probably won’t be). `String::from_utf8` returns `None` in such cases, and so unwrapping that panics.